# Protractor file upload hanging after send keys on IE11. Works on Chrome/Firefox

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor, test-strategy, ie11

I have a `Protractor/Cucumber` script, that successfully uploads a file on `Chrome/Firefox`. When I run the same script on `IE11`, then the website hangs with the file dialog box open and no file sent.

The only error message I get is

`"UnsupportedOpperationError: Error 404: Not Found."`

My HTML for the upload is basic

`<input name="myFile" type="file">`

I have also sent the absolute path:

`C:\fullpath`

I am using `selenium standalone server 3.5.0` and `IEDriver 3.4.0 (32-bit)`

From my research, there has been an issue with `IE` and the security or advanced settings. Unfortunately, as this is a business project I'm unable to configure the settings for `IE`. The workaround being adding the `ignoreProtectedModeSettings`: true to the capabilities. For my capabilities, I have used

```
capabilites : { 
    browserName: 'internet explorer',
    platform: 'windows',
    version: '11',
    maxInstances: 1,
    ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true,
    'ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout': 10000 //I read this might have been an issue but didn't change anything
    nativeEvents: true,
    unexpectedAlertBehavior: 'accept',
    enablePersistentHover: true,
    ignoreZoomSettings: true,
    requireWindowsFocus: true,
    'disable-popup-blocking': true,
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
    INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS: true
}
```

My code for uploading the file is also basic `element(by.css('input[type="file"])).sendKeys(absolutePath)`

Any ideas or examples would be helpful!

Comment: If you can explicitly add wait before upload for 2-3 sec? Hv you tried? I had implemented same functionality for Chrome and IE11. Which is working. If this doesn't work then will check  system config n other versions

Comment: Hi Narendra, I have tried to add a wait and the result is the same hanging on the file explorer popup.

Comment: Have you verified, Page loaded completely before sendKeys() & Manually its working on IE?

Comment: @DevinPatrickAshcraft why are you opening file explorer when using send keys ? don't click browser button just use sendkeys and then clic

Comment: @PDHide , I am not clicking the browse button, I am only using sendkeys. Sendkeys opens the file explorer, the same thing on firefox and chrome the file explorer opens but closes automatically.

Comment: is the issue just with your applicaiton ? did you try other application

Comment: @NarendraChandrate I am sure that the page has loaded. I have waited for the browse button to be selectable. Manually I am able to use the browse button and upload a file and use the website. I am fairly sure there is an issue because I am unable to set the [Required Configurations](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) on the IE browser. Specifically the protected mode settings, or the registry entry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19583107/6793637 did you tried using action class ?

Comment: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions

Comment: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions_exports_LegacyActionSequence.html

Comment: @PDHide I will take a look!

Comment: @PDHide So I tried the action class. I could not click on the element to bring it into focus so I tabbed until the browse was the focus. Once I had the focus I ran sendKeys with the file path and it opened the file explorer and the application started hanging. Just for a test, I used sendkeys to a textbox and it worked fine.

Comment: Can you try sendkeys to the parent element of input tag instead of input

Comment: I sent it to the parent element. The focus was not set on the file upload and the text was sent to the previously highlighted element which was a text box.